# Google maps area / district / neighborhood info

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to find out where I can get district / neighborhood info for google maps for integrating it on my site.

I'm looking for dutch info so I can display the boundaries / borders of a neighborhood from here in Holland/the Netherlands

---

NL

Hey Mensen,

Ben op zoek naar wijk/buurt info voor in google maps zodat ik de randen van de wijk kan tonen op de kaart, iemand enig idee waar ik dit vandaan kan halen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was very interested to see this to work and dived into it a little bit more.

The CBS provides a REST API to retreive the statistics and polygon data. You can find the API here: http://geoservices.cbs.nl/ArcGis/rest/services/WijkenBuurten2010/MapServer

One thing to note, the coordinates are in esriMeters format, but you can provide a spacial reference ID and let them convert it on the fly. To use these in Google Maps use `4326` as the reference ID and add the parameter `f=json` to get a JSON formatted response. It's then easy to save and use the data the way you want.

And another tip, the coordinates seem to be in reverse. So the latitude is in the array's `[1]` position and the longitude in the `[0]` position.

Comment: No problem! It was good fun to finally get the data sorted.

Another tip btw: the coordinates seem to be in reverse. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this: http://www.cbs.nl/nl-NL/menu/themas/dossiers/nederland-regionaal/publicaties/geografische-data/archief/2011/2011-wijk-en-buurtkaart-2010-art.htm

It's a free to use ESRI shape file with all the borders for all neighbourhoods in The Netherlands. As long as you mention the CBS as a source. Now you only need to find a way to convert the shapes to a Google Maps compatible lat/lon coordinate system. The shape is in the Rijksdriehoekstelsel coordinate system while Google Maps uses the WCS84 system.

Maybe someone knows of a publicly database where all data is already converted?

Comment: converting is indeed the problem, I can't get it to possition right.

Answer (score 0):

I think its called reverse geocoding in google map.. Here is one example of it;

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/geocoding-reverse.html

you can convert the address in another language using google translate API.

Comment: That's for converting from address to geocode
I want to be able to show borders of a neighborhood in google maps